# What is the best way to access XML objects stored as object-relational in Oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle, orm, oracle12c

Firstly, I am using Oracle 12 version 1

I need to retrieve objects stored as object-relational in Oracle Data Base but it is too slow - I am using Dom Documents for doing so.

The function I am using:

```
create or replace FUNCTION XML_myDistance(
  innXML XMLType,
  outXML XMLType
) RETURN number
IS
  total NUMBER := 0;
  docInn xmldom.DOMDocument;
  docOut xmldom.DOMDocument;
  nInn xmldom.DOMNode;
  nOut xmldom.DOMNode;
  nlInn xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  nlOut xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  len number;
BEGIN
--Converte os atributos xmltype para DOMDocuments.
docInn := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(innXML);
docOut := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(outXML);

nlInn := xmldom.getElementsByTagName(docInn, '*');
nlOut := xmldom.getElementsByTagName(docOut, '*');
len := xmldom.getLength(nlInn);

for i in 1..len-1 loop
        nInn := xmldom.item(nlInn, i);
        nOut := xmldom.item(nlOut, i);
        total := total + ABS(xmldom.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(nInn)) - xmldom.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(nOut)));
end loop;

DBMS_XMLDOM.freeDocument(docInn);
DBMS_XMLDOM.freeDocument(docOut);

RETURN total;
END;
/
```

I have tried through the following query too... but its performance is even worse...

```
create or replace FUNCTION myDistance(
  innXML XMLType,
  outXML XMLType
) RETURN number
IS
  total NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM( ABS(oFV.feature - iFV.feature) )
  INTO   total
  FROM   XMLTABLE(
           '//FeatureVector/feature'
           PASSING outXML
           COLUMNS rn       FOR ORDINALITY,
                   feature  NUMBER  PATH '.'
         ) oFV
         INNER JOIN
         XMLTABLE(
           '//FeatureVector/feature'
           PASSING innXML
           COLUMNS rn       FOR ORDINALITY,
                   feature  NUMBER  PATH '.'
         ) ifv
         ON ( oFV.rn = iFV.rn );

  RETURN total;
END;
/
```

Is there another way to access XML data **stored as object-relational** objects in Oracle? A more efficient one.

Comment: Have you tried indexing `XMLType` columns? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm#i1031628

Comment: Thanks, but It would not work in this case.